# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

The full error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

This is the first time I try to connect a website with this host. I'm not a big PHP developer and most code I see here is somewhat different from what I have seen. I can connect to phpmyadmin but I can't through the website

```php
class Config  
{
    const DB_TYPE = 'mysql';
    const DB_HOST = ' localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'xxxx';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'xxxx';
    const DB_NAME = 'xxxx';
}    

class DatabasePDO {

    /** @var PDO */
    private static $dbh;
    public static function getInstance()
    {

        $dsn = Config::DB_TYPE.':host='.Config::DB_HOST.';dbname='.Config::DB_NAME;

        try {
            self::$dbh = new PDO($dsn, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch( PDOException $e ){
            echo "Error!: ".$e->getMessage();
            die();
        }

        return self::$dbh;
    }
}


require_once WWW_ROOT. 'php' .DS. 'classes' .DS. 'Config.php';
require_once WWW_ROOT. 'php' .DS. 'classes' .DS. 'DatabasePDO.php';

class UserDAO {

    public $dbh;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = DatabasePDO::getInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a white space in localhost. Change config to:

```
class Config  
{
    const DB_TYPE = 'mysql';
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';  // <- fixed this
    const DB_USER = 'xxxx';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'xxxx';
    const DB_NAME = 'xxxx';
}
```